# Mysql Table Partitioned and not not applying CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I am wondering why my default time value has stopped working on my database when I partitioned it into months. MySQL 8.1

Is this normal behavior?

Is there a alternative solution of setting this default value inside MySQL?

Below is the table

```
CREATE TABLE `datalogvalues1` (
  `dlvID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dlvVarID` int NOT NULL,
  `dlvValue` decimal(16,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `dlvCreated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dlvModfied` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dlvID`,`dlvCreated`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (to_days(`dlvCreated`))
(PARTITION `start` VALUES LESS THAN (0) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from202211 VALUES LESS THAN (738855) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from202212 VALUES LESS THAN (738886) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from202301 VALUES LESS THAN (738917) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from202302 VALUES LESS THAN (738945) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from202303 VALUES LESS THAN (738976) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from202304 VALUES LESS THAN (739006) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from202305 VALUES LESS THAN (739037) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from202306 VALUES LESS THAN (739067) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from202307 VALUES LESS THAN (739098) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from202308 VALUES LESS THAN (739129) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from202309 VALUES LESS THAN (739159) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from202310 VALUES LESS THAN (739190) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION from202311 VALUES LESS THAN (739220) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */;
```

Comment: I worked out this was because I had to use the field as a Primary Key.
Even though it did not error it will not add a generated date as it may not be unique.

Comment: Works for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xtrAaZANmZQDYULcdDvGV4/0

Comment: Why are you putting the date in the primary key? The auto increment ID value is already unique.

Comment: @Barmar - I assume the date is added to the primary key not for uniqueness, but to allow the table to be partitioned. I've seen many developers do this to work around the requirement that the partitioning column must be part of the primary key and any other unique keys of the table.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks, forgot about that restriction.